# Combine 4 lines into a single list element

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a fastq file where each 'entry' is 4 lines (Two before the '+' and one after). How would I read each group of 4 lines into individual list elements?

The file looks like:

```
@DQNZZQ1:756:C3K7PACXX:6:1101:2383:2061 1:N:0:CCGTCC
GAACCCCACTGTGCACCACCTGTCTCTTATACACATCTAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGAGATGGGGGCGACGACATTTTTGCAGCTGATGCTAAACGCGGA
+
@@CFFFFFHHHDHJJJIIJJJIHHGGGG<E@C9CDFHG>ABFGGADFHGIGEHCHHGEEC:GHGEH/8=?@99554>CC5CDCCDD=CD44>C@>@@DD@
@DQNZZQ1:756:C3K7PACXX:6:1101:2486:2062 1:N:0:CCGTCC
GCCCAAGACGGCCCCCGCTCCGCGTCGGTTCATCGGTTCCTCGGGGCAAGGATGTTCCCAGGTTGTTTGTGAGGAGAGTGTCTCTTTTTCACATCTTGTG
+
@@@DDDDDFFFFFIIIE8?FG)6@############################################################################
@DQNZZQ1:756:C3K7PACXX:6:1101:2359:2093 1:N:0:CCGTCC
TAAGATATTGGCAAGCAATATAGCTTTCTTCACGCGCCACACAGTTTCCCGGCTGTAGCGGTGACGACGGGGCAGACGGTGGAGGTGTTTCCTGCAGACT
+
@@@?DDFBFHGFD<@GGHCEHFCDHIHGHIIIIIFGIIGEFHGFD@DHFHBEBHGAC3)-99>?ABBB=@&5>;5889B0<<???8848<@@########
@DQNZZQ1:756:C3K7PACXX:6:1101:2319:2168 1:N:0:CCGTCC
AAGTTTAATAAGCAAACCCTGGGAACTGCGACGGTCTTCGGCACTGTCTACAAATGACGCGTCACAGAAGACCTCTAAACCTCGATCCAGTTATCGCTGT
+
==@4:BDBDBB?8AFGHIEHHIII;F3?1?FF?F0????C@FA;DEEGHEC;?=CADCB=A/3'5:@A>?CCC:>@A:49?A<B5>??CCA>>+>18?##
@DQNZZQ1:756:C3K7PACXX:6:1101:2337:2170 1:N:0:CCGTCC
GGCGACTGTGTTTGCCAAGATGGAGCGCGACCTGCGGCGGCCGGGTGCCGTGTTTGCCGAGGCGGGCGCACCCGCCCGCTGGGAGACGGGCCCCAACTAG
+
;=?DD:::DFCCCFGIGIIGGIBCHIIIID@GHIIIBEB>B@B@-)5??B05?AC9>AB5<77@####################################
```

Where I have gotten so far:

```
forward = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
reverse = open(sys.argv[2],'r')
output = open(sys.argv[3],'r')


for reads in forward:
    freads_full = islice(forward, 4)
    for line in freads_full:
        flist = line
```

Thanks for you're help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a recipe called `grouper` in the [`itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that does exactly what you want:

> ```
> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
>     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
>     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
>     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
>     return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
> ```

You can do something like

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as forward: 
    for batch in grouper(forward, 4): 
        # do stuff with the iterator
```

You have a few options as to what you do with the lines. For example, if you want to concatenate them, you can do

```
''.join(batch)
```

or even

```
sum(batch)
```